# how to get filename in php

Tags: php

```
$str = "/d/file/shop/7c0ea5b0b96a490a9c78255ddb559943.jpg";
```

How do I get the filename `7c0ea5b0b96a490a9c78255ddb559943.jpg` from the full path?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/index.php is a great thing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`basename($str);`