# Pick the filename using substr() in PHP

Tags: php, file, path, substr

Let's say I have a filepath-

```
Doc/Monday/File.txt
```

I want to use a substr() to pick just `File.txt` in PHP. How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528091/how-to-get-filename-in-php and a thousand others

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
basename('/some/path/to/file.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode the string with "/" the take the last element of the resultant array

Comment: Why do people like converting strings to array when you can just use string functions?

Comment: @meze Because they have read about `explode()` somewhere, and it seems to be a screwdriver that you can use for everything. Even though a hammer is much more useful for hitting nails.

Comment: Ok sure you can use the string functions, In most cases the requirement never ends finding the file name, If in case we need then first folder before the file name?, then the explode function makes sense

Answer (score 0):

**TRy this**

```
$data= pathinfo('/some/path/to/file.txt');    

echo $data['basename'];
```